# How to use google-api-python-client package in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-slides-api

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1, with Python 3.10 interpreter.
I am trying to use the google-api-python-client to add elements to a Google Slide.

I've tried `import googleapiclient`, but it does not recognize the package. When I click the context actions, it fails with message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement googleapiclient (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for googleapiclient
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 23.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\generic-user-name\PycharmProjects\generic-project-name\generic-user-name\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've tried installing it through the terminal, which has path `C:\Users\generic-user-name\PycharmProjects\generic-user-name`. I used the command `pip install google-api-python-client` and `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`, both of which did not work even while reloading everything from disk.

How do I use [this package](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) properly? Is this even the correct one for editing Google Slide elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use virutalenv and install package there https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html

```
python3 -m venv env
env/bin/pip3 install google-api-python-client
env/bin/python3 C:\Users\generic-user-name\PycharmProjects\generic-user-name
```

Comment: What do you mean by `env/bin/pip3 install google-api-python-client` and `env/bin/python3 C:\Users\generic-user-name\PycharmProjects\generic-user-name
`?

Comment: Install the dependency into virtualenv, if you read the guide, you will get more context